# read username from modified /etc/passwd file using a script

Tags: bash, shell, passwd

I want to read the users from /etc/passwd file.My /etc/passwd file is

```
/etc/passwd

root:eRYFFjZ2./oo:0:0:root:/:/bin/bash
nobody:*:99:99:Nobody:/:
ftp:*:14:50:FTP User:/:/bin/false
#guest
guest:/QP8Q2QieMWi4:500:500:Guest:/:/bin/bash
gst1:x:1002:1003:,,,:/home/gst1:/bin/bash
#gend
#admin
ad1:x:1003:1004:,,,:/home/adm1:/bin/bash
ad2:x:1004:1005:,,,:/home/adm2:/bin/bash
#adend
```

I want to get users from this file using a script.first read guest and gst1 .Then ad1,ad2.
i tried to use

```
awk'#guest/{flag-1;next}/#gend/{flag=0}flag' /etc/passwd
awk'#admin/{flag-1;next}/#adend/{flag=0}flag' /etc/passwd
```

this gives me two lines

```
guest:/QP8Q2QieMWi4:500:500:Guest:/:/bin/bash
gst1:x:1002:1003:,,,:/home/gst1:/bin/bash
ad1:x:1003:1004:,,,:/home/adm1:/bin/bash
ad2:x:1004:1005:,,,:/home/adm2:/bin/bash
```

I want to extract first 'guest' do some operation with it then extract 'gst1' .
Then i want to extract admin users names(ad1 and ad2)

Is it possible to extract them one by one in a while loop.I want like this

```
start from label #guest
get user 'guest'
===do some work with 'guest'===
continue above steps for the users up to label #gend
```

I am running this linux in a embedded target and the file systems are custom built .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following GNU sed command:

```
sed '0,/#guest/d;/#gend/,$d;s/:.*//' /etc/passwd
```

`0,/#guest/d` removes all lines until `#guest` (including it).

`/#gend/,$d` removes everything from `#gend` to the end of input which is expressed using a `$`. (in GNU sed)

`s/:.*//` deletes everything from the first `:` to the end of the line for the remaining lines.

Output:

```
guest
gst1
```

If want to "do something" with the user names, use a `while` loop together with `read`:

```
sed '0,/#guest/d;/#gend/,$d;s/:.*//' /etc/passwd | while read user ; do
    echo "$user"
    do something ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `:` as record separator and take advantage of record variables. Let's print a simple message:

```shell
 awk -F: '/#guest/{flag=1;next} /#gend/ {flag=0} flag { print "work with \"" $1 "\""}' /etc/passwd
```

But you may also run an external command providing the username as parameter, changing the `print` statement to a `system` call.

Eg. let's list the user home dir content (using the sixth column content of `/etc/passwd`):

```shell
awk -F: '/#guest/{flag=1;next} /#gend/{flag=0} flag { system("ls " $6) }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: this prints both users.i am looking for a way to take one at a time(guest),do some work with that user .Then take the next user(gst1) ,do the same work with that .. continue up to the end flag #gend

Comment: feel free to replace the print statement with some other treatment, using `$2` to get the username. Could you provide more details on the kind of work you plan to do?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a loop around the output:

```
awk'#guest/{flag-1;next}/#gend/{flag=0}flag' /etc/passwd | while read pwline
do
   # do what you want to do with guest users
done

awk'#admin/{flag-1;next}/#adend/{flag=0}flag' /etc/passwd | while read pwline
do
   # do what you want to do with admin users
done
```